# Why am I receiving the error: "Missing script: Start"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dotenv

I'm trying to follow a tutorial for starting up my first NodeJS app, but I don't understand why I am getting this error. I'm attempting to connect a MongoDB database with the app, and obviously had to modify my Start.js file in order to do that... but the error says I'm missing that file completely. Here's my Start.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection
  .on('connected', () => {
    console.log(`Mongoose connection open on ${process.env.DATABASE}`);
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`);
  });

const app = require('./app');
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Express is running on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

I was told to create a `.env` file to place in the project folder as well, could this have something to do with it? Maybe the address to the database is incorrect? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "demo-node-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "nodemon ./start.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.3",
    "pug": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: show your package.json most likely you don't have a "start" script

Comment: @C.Gochev I just added it. Doesn't "watch" do the job?

Comment: no, if you start you application with `npm start` there has to be a "start" script.In your case you have watch so you run `npm run watch` you can name them however you like and you run them with `npm run [script-name]`

Comment: @C.Gochev I've been doing "npm run watch", but I still get the error

Comment: maybe your start.js is in the wrong directory or is with a different case. in your question you wrote it with a capital Start.js so it has to be the same way in the package.json I am 99% sure your problem is with capitalization :D

Comment: @C. Gochev that's what I wrote in the post, but not in my file. Everything was working fine until I made these edits, so I guess I need to just retrace my steps

Comment: @C.Gochev Well, it seems my issue has been solved. Just commented out the problematic code, reinstalled one of the packages I was using, then uncommented it. Everything seems to be working now.